# How to make div appear only when specific item from list is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got this code:

```
<form>
<select name="lelel">
  <option value="x">x</option>
  <option value="xx">xx</option>
  <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="divid">
  LALALALALA
</div>
```

And my question is, can i make the div "divid" be invisible and then when the user selects the option xxx the div will appear.

Comment: are you allowed to use jquery/js?

Comment: write a function in javascript that changes the css of the div on change

Comment: do you want to specifically use PHP for this because the Javascript answer by Gibberish is the correct answer. (and saves you a POST request)

Comment: Yes, i can use javascript

Comment: The POST request is already used, i didnt specify here but on my code i have php form method=post if thats what your'e talking about..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$('[name=lelel]').change(function(){
    if ( this.value == 'xxx') {
       $('#divid').show();
    }else{
       $('#divid').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
#divid {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select name="lelel">
  <option value="x">x</option>
  <option value="xx">xx</option>
  <option value="xxx">xxx</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="divid">
  LALALALALA
</div>
```

Comment: i'm guessing it has to dissapear again when you deselect, probably should be a toggle, add else {
       $('#divid').hide();
    } ?

Comment: And how can i make it disappear when he deselects it? :D

Answer (score 1):

If you were going to have several divs that appear/disappear based on user selection you could do the follow with the JS code expanding on gibberish's answer

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var chosen_one = $(this).value();
  $('.toShow').hide();
  $('#'+chosen_one).show();
})
```

You can then give all the divs that will be shown/hidden a class of `toShow` and set them as `display: none;` in the CSS. Then as you add more options/divs you don't have to modify your JS or CSS